# Is there a way to resume music after finishing a call

Tags: calls, music

When I am listening to music and making a call through a Bluetooth device in my car, after the phone call, the music is not resumed. Is there a way to cause the audio player to resume the music after the phone call?

Comment: Mine does. What device and OS? Are you using the Google Music app?

Answer (score 1):

I removed "Viber " application and now it resumes music after phone call

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Autostarts app to edit the end-phone-call event and add your music app from the list of apps that get alerted on that event. I believe it requires root.

Comment: Could you link the app?

Comment: F-droid: https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.elsdoerfer.android.autostarts

Comment: Play Store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.elsdoerfer.android.autostarts&hl=en